# Disable Motif Drag&Drop functionality

Tags: motif

I have developed an application in X/Motif that has a performance issue related with the standard Drag&Drop functionality supplied by the toolkit. I have already disabled the Drag&Drop protocol at the level of the user interface by setting the XmDRAG_NONE resources:

- dragInitiatorProtocolStyle: XmDRAG_NONE
- dragReceiverProtocolStyle: XmDRAG_NONE

This effectively disables the Drag&Drop HMI standard features, but the properties / atoms’ (in _MOTIF_DRAG_WINDOW) related to this functionality continue to be created in the Root Window every time widgets such as XmText (or others with Drag&Drop capability) are instantiated by the application.

- Is there a way to force a complete disable of the Drag&Drop?
- If not, is there a way to safely remove the Drag&Drop properties/atoms in the Root Window?

Thanks in advance.